# Hiding dots from pagecontroller, monotouch iphone

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, uipagecontrol

I want to design some thing like this for iphone based on monotouch:

[image]

each row has some buttons and by dragging rows to the right or left you can access them icons.

A way that i think to implement this, is embedding 3 page controller (one for each row) and add each two icon in one view.

The question is this:
Is using view pager the best way to implement this?

If yes, how can I hide the dots in below of pagecontroller to create a page like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing terms.

A Page Control is a interface element that marks the position of a UIScrollView.

You should be using a UIScrollView (without the Page Control) for that.

Not to be confused with the UIPageViewController, which is kind of a Paged Scroll View with page curl effect included.